# Identifying a JavaScript error on a list with 700 "entries"

Tags: javascript

I'm modifying a website that I don't coded but my boss ask me to do.

I see a javascript error on Firebug that says: **missing ] after element list**

In the end of the file processed with PHP, there is two lists with 771 elements. One is called **list1** and the other **listaid**. First contains the names and the second the ids of the list.

You can see the code:
http://pastebin.com/Ctji5Qx9

How I can evaluate where is the error on the list? I can't see it with this amount of elements and the highlight don't shows any error...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That pastebin code is blank with the message `- Unknown paste ID, it may have expired or been deleted!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editor highlighting showed that the strings in list1 aren't properly escaped. You have `"JUNTA DE COMPENSACIÓ "ADOBERIES-EST""` and `"JUNTA DE COMPENSACION PROVISIONAL DEL PLAN PARCIAL DEL SECTOR G "CAN OLIVERES""`. So escape the `"`s and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jslint: [jslint.com](http://www.jslint.com)
Just paste your JS code in it and it will check and return you a useful answere.